# Tableau Relative Percents

Tags: tableau-api

How can I calculate percents by row that depend on the total of another single row? For instance, in the table below, all percents are based on the grand total of the first category, "Rectangles."

```
    Category      Distinct   Percent  
 --------------- ---------- --------- 
  Rectangles           100   100%     
  Squares               90   90%      
  Squares (4x4)         70   70%      
  Squares (8x8)         10   10%
```

In the example above, 'category' and 'distinct' would be given, and I would want 'percent' to be a calculated field by taking `distinct/distinct_Rectangles`.

Comment: Your question is still unclear for me. Can you elaborate with one more example? Will be happy to help !

Comment: please share your desired output.